# Как получить директорию из другого git репозитория?

Tags: git, devops

Есть репозиторий с библиотекой ui-компонентов структура репозитория примерно такая:

```
/packages
 /components
 /utils
 ...
.gitignore
README.md
```

И есть проект который использует эти компоненты из библиотеки, структура репозитория примерно такая же только уже в папке `packages` лежат пакеты которые принадлежат именно этому проекту, а не общим компонентам:

```
/packages
 /domain
 /dashboard
 ...
.gitignore
README.md
```

Мне нужно что бы в папке `packages` находились все пакеты из библиотеки компонентов и пакеты которые принадлежат этому проекту. Причём если что то меняется в пакетах которые принадлежат библиотеке то должна быть возможность запушить или запулить изменения

Первое что можно нагуглить это `git submodules`. Если добавлять библиотеку компонентов как сабмодуль в репозиторий с проектом, то получается такая структура репозитория:

```
/packages
 /domain
 /dashboard
   /packages
     /components
     /utils
     ...
   .gitignore
   README.md
.gitignore
README.md
```

А моя цель это:

```
/packages
 /domain
 /dashboard
 /components
 /utils
.gitignore
README.md
```

При этом сабмодули решают проблему с версионированием библиотеки компонентов. Можно ли спулить только одну папку из другого репозитория?

Answer (score 0):

> Можно ли спулить только одну папку из другого репозитория?

Нет. `git pull` это по сути `git fetch` + `git merge`. Единицей является коммит, поэтому - не получится. И гит не позволит использовать два совершенно разных репо, это не `rsync`.

Можно использовать submodules + поставить симлинки для красоты.

Comment: Я смотрел в сторону `git subtree split` + `git submodule`. Т.е. через `git subtree split` выделить в отдельную ветку все комиты которые затрагивают изменения в папке `/packages` в репозитории с библиотекой и потом через сабиодули уже использовать эту ветку, но тогда я буду комитета в ветку и как это синхронизировать с дефолтной веткой (master) не понятно

Comment: @Pavel, `git subtree` - я про это не знал, не могу сказать. Но на мой взгляд вы пытаетесь скрестить ужа с ежом. Наверное, так можно. Получится нетрадиционное решение. Есть еще пакетный подход. npm, composer. Наверное, знаете. А чем не устраивает?